# Vuejs registering vuefire globally

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vuefire

So i have installed vuefire and i have

in `main.js`

```
var Vue = require('vue')
var VueFire = require('vuefire')
var firebase = require('firebase')

Vue.use(VueFire)
var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({ ... })
var db = firebaseApp.database()
```

Now am stuck on how to register firebase globally so that inside a component i can simply do

```
export default{
 mounted(){
   this.$firebase....
   }
 }
```

How do i register firebase globally in the main.js file so that in other components i dont need to always initialize firebase configuration and database

Answer (score 1):

We also need to initiate the firebase connection. Create a new file called `firebase.js`.

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({
  // Populate your firebase configuration data here.
  ...
});

// Export the database for components to use.
// If you want to get fancy, use mixins or provide / inject to avoid redundant imports.
export const db = firebaseApp.database();
```

Then just use in another component user

```
<template>
  <p v-for="user of users">
    {{user.name}}
  </p>
</template>
<script>
import {db} from './firebase';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: {}
    }
  },

  firebase: {
    users: {
      source: db.ref('users'),
      // Optional, allows you to handle any errors.
      cancelCallback(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What about when i would only like to subscribe to events alone not read data from firebase, Example whenever a change in a node happens i would like to execute a method, so probably a subscritption . How can i then go about this.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI to which events you want to subscribe? Plese attach example on https://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is like following.
1. make a plugin in src/plugins/firebaseApp.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
const config = {
  apiKey: "<your key>",
  authDomain: "<your domain>",
  databaseURL: "https://<your URL>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<your projectId>",
}
export default firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

2. at main.js

```
...
import firebaseApp from './plugins/firebaseApp'
...

new Vue({
  ...
  firebaseApp,
  ...
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```